# Trick Windows to understand Mac file paths

Tags: windows, macos, path

I'm looking for a efficient way to open Mac paths in windows. I explain the situation:

I am using a software on my mac, which links to files located on a network drive. When i open the same "project" in the windows version of this software, on another PC machine, i want it to link to the files seamlessly. (both machines are, of course, connected to the network drive)

Lets assume my file is here (mac path) : /Volumes/NetworkDrive/Project/Test/MyFile.txt the equivalent path in windows is: \MyServer\NetworkDrive\Project\Test\MyFile.txt

What i would like, is to trick windows, either in the registry, environment variable, or anything like this that is "over" any softwares, so "/Volumes/NetworkDrive" would be understood as "\MyServer\NetworkDrive"

That way any file in any software could be opened.

I would like this to work pretty much like the hosts file works for ip addresses (creating aliases and re-routing for servers)

OR - is this could be done mounting fake folders ? The trick could be done either on mac or pc, as long as it works !

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is simply impossible in Win32. You would be able to achieve this by means of a subsystem (such as SUA) or an emulation layer such as Cygwin only.

Forward and back slashes aren't the issue here, because Windows understands these just fine.

No solution on Windows (or rather in the Win32 subsystem) is going to provide what you want across all programs. While you could write a shell extension to make Windows Explorer show this the way you want, the command prompt and other programs won't have a clue as the shell namespace is pretty much confined to Explorer (and other file management tools that choose to implement it).

The closest you could possibly get is to share (via Samba) the `/Volumes/NetworkDrive` out, renaming your machine to `Volumes` and naming the share `NetworkDrive`. This way prepending another slash (or back slash), i.e. `\\Volumes\NetworkDrive`, will yield something close to what you want.

While unixoid systems such as Mac have a single root, the Win32 subsystem (which is the user-visible part of all modern Windows versions) has multiple roots (each drive letter). The OS itself has a notion of a single "object root" (much akin to how it works on unixoid systems), but that is beyond the scope of the question (in case you are curious, read "Windows Internals" and tinker with WinObj from [Sysinternals](http://live.sysinternals.com/)).